# How to detect IE7 with javascript or jquery and add a class to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

Is there any way to detect IE7?

I don't have any problems with my codes in IE8, but I have a problem with IE7.

So what I thought is that I can add a class with jquery when a browser is IE7 detecting it by javascript.

I want to change from

```
<div id="system">
```

to

```
<div id="system" class="ie7">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this issue related to styles or JavaScript? If this is a style-related thing, you should consider using conditional comments like suggested. If this is a JavaScript thing, you should read about feature detection, which beats browser sniffing in a lot of ways.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use an IE conditional comment to add the class via javascript, something like this:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#system').addClass('ie7');
});
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 49):

if you really want to solve this by using javascript you might want to check the version like this:

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 7.") != -1)
    $('#system').addClass('ie7');
```

Comment: +1 for a solution that does not depend on the available options of a javascript framework, or conditional comments.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it just with HTML:

**css**

```
.ie7{
   padding: 0;
   color: red;
}
```

**html**

```
<!--[if IE 7 ]> <div id="system" class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 7)|!(IE)]><!--> <div id="system"> <!--<![endif]-->
</div>
```

This creates the `div` with the class `ie7` if executed in internet explorer 7. All other browser and IE > 7 would just create that div without the class.

Comment: I think he is wanting a jQuery solution. However, your solution is a better way to go since a user could have javascript disabled.

Comment: +1. I usually do this in one place, on `<body class="ie7">`, and use a CSS containment selector like `body.ie7 #system`, to avoid having to repeat conditional comments throughout the document.

Answer (score 9):

To detect ie7 just use

```
if($.browser.msie && parseFloat($.browser.version) < 8){
    //do other stuff
    return;
}
```

To do what you want with it just:

```
if($.browser.msie && parseFloat($.browser.version) < 8){
    $('#system').addClass('ie7');
}
```

Comment: At this time (2 years later), `.browser` has been removed from jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#system').addClass('ie7');
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few different ways:

- http://gmatter.wordpress.com/2006/11/21/another-way-to-detect-ie7-in-javascript/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/#jQuery.browser.version2
- http://ajaxian.com/archives/detecting-ie7-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Please be informed that IE8 compat view will also have `<!--[if IE 7 ]>`  as true

So you should do a second level test on the document mode, if you dont want the changes to be reflecting in IE8 Compat view.

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
   try
    {
    if(document.documentMode!=8){
     //Your code comes here
    }
    }
    catch(exception){
    }
   </script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```