# disable a javascript only in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, internet-explorer-7

I got a scenario where I need a JavaScript to load in all browsers except IE7. Any help is greatly appreciated. I've tried the below code:

```
<!--[if gt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Some script XXX to execute
</script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<script type="text/javascript">    
    //Some script XXX to execute
</script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: What is this nonsense??

Comment: if you are using jquery why not use it to detect browser version and do a conditional execution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional comment for 'Except IE8'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692129/conditional-comment-for-except-ie8)

Comment: I marked the duplicate, same idea, instead of 8, use 7.

Answer (score 1):

I think this works too

```
<!--[if !(IE 7)]>
   // tag here
<![endif]-->
```

You can also do a combination of

```
<![if !IE]>
   // script tag
<![endif]>

<!--[if (gte IE 8)&(lt IE 7)]>
   // script tag
<![endif]-->
```

see docs here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I am not sure if you are looking to load an entire file or just a few lines of script. If it's only a few lines the jquery way is easier

Answer (score 0):

Use `navigator.userAgent` to check the browser identification. 
[also see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670138/how-to-detect-ie7-with-javascript-or-jquery-and-add-a-class-to-div)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if ( $.browser.msie == true &&  $.browser.version < 8) {
           //code for ie 7
        }
else
{
       document.write("<script src=\"test.js\">");
}
```

Comment: note that $.browser got removed from jQuery with version 1.9.

Comment: This question isn't tagged with _jQuery_ (although it is used in code)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're already on the right lines with [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
<!--[if !(IE 7)]>--><script>alert("I'm not IE7");</script><!--<![endif]-->
```

To any non-IE browser, this becomes

```
<!--[if !(IE 7)]>-->                     Comment
<script>alert("I'm not IE7");</script>   Element
<!--<![endif]-->                         Comment
```

To any IE browser, this becomes

```
<!--[if !(IE 7)]>                        If not IE 7
-->                                      (continued) AND Comment
<script>alert("I'm not IE7");</script>   Element
<!--<![endif]-->                         Comment AND End if
```

From which, if it is IE 7, it gets snipped.

```
<!--[if !(IE 7)]>                        If - not rendered
                                         SNIP
<![endif]-->                             End If
```

You could reduce this down if you don't mind invalid HTML

```
<![if !(IE 7)]><script>alert("I'm not IE7");</script><![endif]>
```